# Where were the cannons in final fight in Wakanda in Infinity War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Black Panther*, Ulysses Klaue describes his arm cannon as a leaf blower in comparison to the cannons/weapons that Wakanda has.

*Infinity War* comes after the events of Black Panther, so the weapons should exist. During the final fight with the children of Thanos and Space Dogs (as Rocket refers to them), Wakandans could have used these powerful cannons, pointing them at the opened section of barrier. Instead they chose a fist fight.

Even M'Baku says that it would be the end of Wakanda, so the magnitude is huge and risks are very high. Why were these powerful weapons not used?

---

**Edit 1:** I watched the movie again and planes are there in the fight. But they were only used to destroy the spaceships that crashed.

Comment: I always thought this was meant as, "they have" weapons/cannons/technology that dwarf what Klaue was using. Not that they had specific cannons deployed around Wakanda.

Comment: @Jared we can agree they have special weapons. Now these weapons are not distributed around world(*What **killmonger** was trying to do*). So these weapons are in wakanda. Given the magnitude of the fight, anyone would choose to use their primary weapons. So yes, they could have deployed them on battle front. They even have fighter planes that could have been beneficial.

Comment: "Given the magnitude of the fight, anyone would choose to use their primary weapons. So yes, they could have deployed them on battle front." No, not necessarily. Would you expect the U.S. to use nuclear weapons in a battle right outside of Washington, D.C.?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Nukes, no. War helicopters/planes, yes. Even an armored Hummer with .50 cals., but I'm sure they won't go there with USPs and Stun guns. Only weapons used in the mentioned fight were spear with fire utility, which is like using a Pistol. Even the Rhinos used in Black Panther were more effective. I understand they were killed in that fight, so cannot be used. But being so powerful nation, they should have used some heavy artillery.

Comment: Projectile weapons would have been a friendly fire risk to the infantry that rushed forward to engage in melee combat, obviously. :)

Comment: @BenOsborne that's the point. Why do a melee war when you have such weapons. Also when they decided to open barrier, they could have moved out of the way for these weapons and go for melee kills for remaining few

Comment: I just thought that the writers of IW didn't think Black Panther would be as successful as they originally thought, hence the short screen time for most of them, and possibly the lack of extra tech that could've been more useful. Then again, they didn't do so bad in the battle, it was the snap that did them in

Comment: We've never seen them, so we don't actually know what these guns are like. You're assuming they're (easily) portable and can be aimed wherever you like. They could instead be stationary weapons intended purely for anti-aircraft purposes (i.e. they only shoot at flying objects, not targets on the ground).

Comment: Where exactly did you see this quote from Ulysses Klaue? Can you find it in some transcript or video clip? I suspect you might have misinterpreted it, and good chance there aren't really such weapons.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That was in Black Panther when he in interrogated. I'll share link later.

Comment: @Rajesh hmm... so he might have been lying, I saw the movie but don't remember that specific scene. When you add please let me know, I'll take a look.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist We did see Klaw use that arm canon in Black Panther. And thats a mining tool. So  at least that was available. They must even have bigger form of mining tools that can be weaponize. Also, there are air-crafts capable of attack shown in black panther. They could have been used

Comment: Related to the aircrafts not being used: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Wakandans-not-use-their-aircraft-during-the-Avengers-Infinity-War-They-had-air-superiority

Comment: @ShadowWizard https://youtu.be/0RVdZQwUryY. Jump to 2.50

Comment: hmm... Well, good chance he was just lying. Will try to find some official-ish source to have an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The actual quote being referred to is, after mentioning Vibranium;

> KLAUE "It powers their city, their tech... their weapons"
>
> ROSS "Weapons?"
>
> KLAUE "Makes my arm cannon look like a leaf blower!"

There is no specific mention of cannons in the text, and there is no requirement for Wakanda to have them. They are a tribal entity and, existing in relative secrecy as a technologically ascendent nation, do not participate in open warfare. Given their defensive capabilities, it would seem they have never faced an invasion.

Their battles are minor skirmishes against interlopers, what use would they have for stationary armament? The city is both cloaked and shielded, Wakanda's MO is to deny intruders, not engage them... until the events of Infinity way, that is.

As per some of the comments above; this is the same reason they do not have tanks, helicopters, ICBMs... they have never had need for them. The jets intended use is seemingly for concealed transportation with some defensive armaments, instead of loaded up with ordnance. They are interceptors, not bombers, which makes sense given Wakanda's use of them. *They could* perhaps have been deployed during the battle, if there are many left after Ross destroyed those trying to escape with Vibranium at the end of *Black Panther*.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. Please check that. Also, *if there are many left*, considering Ross destroyed all, you still have 2. One Black Panther's jet and other Quin Jet in which Cap and others came. And this jet is a battle plane.